# How to a synchronize tasks?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Say I have an async method which saves to file:

```
async Task SaveToFileAsync()
{
   var file = await folder.GetFileAsync ( ...)
   var stream = file.OpenFileAsync(...)
   ///etc

}
```

Now imagine that SaveToFileAsync is called twice simultaneously. This is a problem because you can't write on the same file simultaneously

If this were a regular method, lock() would fix this:

```
void SaveToFile()
{
   lock(something)
   {
      /// code here
   }
}
```

However, lock is not allowed in an async method.

Of course, one could call Monitor.Enter() or use a mutex but these objects work with threads, not tasks. Therefore they are not the answer.

So since lock() is not an option, how can synchronize multiple tasks?
In particular, what code should I write to ensure that "SaveToFileAsync" is called only once at a time?

Comment: Isn't *"SaveToFileAsync" is called only once at a time* stating that you would like to use the method for exactly the opposite of what it was designed for?

Comment: @Jeff the only thing that comes to mind is that you want to save to 2 different files asynchronously but want to synchronize access to the same file...

Comment: You could use a queue that a seperate worker process operates on.

Comment: Disable the `Save` button as the first step of the task and re-enable it as the final step.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For an async mutual exclusion mechanism, have a look at

[Building Async Coordination Primitives, Part 6: AsyncLock](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx)

You could use the `AsyncLock` class follows:

```
private readonly AsyncLock m_lock = new AsyncLock();

async Task SaveToFileAsync()
{
    using (await m_lock.LockAsync()) 
    { 
        var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(...);
        var stream = await file.OpenFileAsync(...);
        // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is AsyncLock (and other synchronization patterns) not integral part of the TPL?

Comment: The `Part 6` post doesn't give copy/paste code. Another blogger aggregated it here tho: http://sanjeev.dwivedi.net/?p=292